# pop a modal out of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

Hello I am using jquery simplemodal to create modal boxes in an application. I would like to be able to pop up the modal above an iframe in order to make it larger and not have the iframe scroll.

right now the code I have for the Modal is like this

```
function fullScreenChart(){
            var pathname = window.location.href;
            var modalHTML = '<iframe src="'+pathname+'&bigchart" width="820px" height="520px" frameborder=0 />';
            $.modal (modalHTML,{
                closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' style='position:absolute; top:0px; right:6px;' class='simplemodal-close'>Close</a>",
                    overlayCss: {
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                        cursor: 'wait'
                     },
                containerCss: {
                        height: 520,
                        width: 820
             }})
                }
```

is there some way I can utilize the .parent() or something to have the modal break out of the iframe. This way I can also make the height and width percentages.

Comment: Did you have any issues implementing my suggestion below?

Comment: I never implemented it that would work for me however there is just too much JS already for me to want to put a function used by one button on the page wrapper for every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would like the parent page to create a modal window and place it over top an iframe. Assuming iframe source is pointing to the same domain, you can simple place your `fullScreenChart` function in the parent page and call it from the iframe like this:

```
parent.fullScreenChart();
```